# how to create 2 column (left side 190px,right auto) layout with Yii 1.1?

Tags: html, css, layout, yii

i'm a new Yiier, i have a question that how could creat 2 colume layout with yii 1.1, 
i means the width 190px of left div is for menu, the right is for body,the width of right is  100%,and i need a div as footer under the body div,height is 50px.
Thank you very much for your Help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two column div layout with fluid left and fixed right column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645986/two-column-div-layout-with-fluid-left-and-fixed-right-column)

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using default Yii layout and style.

You should enable column2 layout in the controller of the views where you need 2 column. Or if you need it project wise do it in *protected/components/Controller.php* as every Controller extends this one.

So the property declartion is:

```
public $layout = "column2";
```

This file can be found under *protected/views/layouts/column2.php*

In this file you will find two divs with classes **span-5** and **span-19**. If you open *screen.css* you will see widths of those classes 190px and 750px respectively. In the div with class-5 you can find widget CMenu in a Portlet which you should use for your menu, it is getting item list from property **$menu** which is simple associative array.

Similar property declaration as before:

```
public $menu = array(array("label"=>"Hello", "url"=>"world.com"));
```

Now that you have set up this, you will find your menu on the right side, you can easily rearange this. Put the div with class *span-5* **under** the div  with class *span-19* and **move** class *last* from span-5 to span-19

The div *footer* doesn't have property height defined which means it expands but you can easily add your own style with property height set to 50px and maybe add overflow: hidden which will hide everything that goes beyond 50px. You add these properties in your own file under *../protected/css/* directory and call it with

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/css/yourFileName.css","screen, projection");
```